# decision making based on buttons

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to make a decision based on the buttons that is displayed in a page. Either  "Save" button  or both "Save & Add Another" and "Save" button will be displayed.

If it's just save button the xpath is `"//input[@value='Save']"`
If both the buttons are displayed the xapth of "Save and Add Another" is `"//input[@value='Save & Add Another']"`  xpath of `"Save " is "//input[@value='Save']"`

My if condition is

```
if(driver.findElements(By.xpath("//input[@value='Save & Add Another']")).size() == 0){

}else{

}
```

Note : There is no id for the buttons
The above implementation works fine but it take a minute to evaluate "if condition".

Is there a way to make this decision fast?

Answer (score 0):

XPath are usually slow and if you are on IE, it's going to be even slow.

Give a try having the condition using CSS Selectors.

```
if(driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("input[value='Save & Add Another']")).size() == 0){

}else{

}
```

Or, if you want to check both "save" and "save & add another" use the below:

```
if(driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("input[value*='Save']")).size() == 0){

}else{

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you have defined a [implicit wait](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp) somewhere:

> An implicit wait is to tell WebDriver to poll the DOM for a certain amount of time when trying to find an element or elements if they are not immediately available.

So you either configure a shorter timeout or do a search which will always return at least 1 element immediately:

```
driver.findElements(By.xpath("//input[starts-with(@value, 'Save')]"))
```